# elasticsearch find documents where the given number items in array has the same property value

Tags: elasticsearch

first of all I would like to show simplified structure of document.

```
{
  "_id": "413123123",
  "_source": {
    "description": {
      "firstLine": "this is my description",
      "secondLine": "some value"
    },
    "InsertDetails": {
      "Timestamp": "2020-06-12T11:14:36+0000"
    },
    "Links": [
      {
        "LinkDetails": {
          "linkId": 2342,
          "type": "Link",
          "dateCreation": "2012-09-21T08:42:09+0000",
          "typeId": 404019,
          "typeOfLink": "http"
        }
      },
      {
        "LinkDetails": {
          "linkId": 321313,
          "type": "Link",
          "dateCreation": "2012-08-21T08:42:09+0000",
          "typeId": 404019,
          "typeOfLink": "http"
        }
      },
      {
        "LinkDetails": {
          "linkId": 1231,
          "type": "Link",
          "dateCreation": "2012-09-21T08:42:09+0000",
          "typeId": 32323,
          "typeOfLink": "https"
        }
      },
      {
        "LinkDetails": {
          "linkId": 53434,
          "type": "Link",
          "dateCreation": "2012-11-21T08:42:09+0000",
          "typeId": 123231,
          "typeOfLink": "wss"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a problem with forming query, which would find documents, where the following requirements are met:

- two items in Links arrays has typeOfLink equal to http
- description string contains word "this"
- found items will be sorted by date desc

The version of elasticsearch is 2.3.2

I've tried with query such like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "Links.LinkDetails.typeOfLink": "http"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "description.firstLine": "this"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "InsertDetails.Timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that this query returns me also the documents, which has only one item in the array with the given value. I've tried to modify this query in different ways, but without any luck.

Added mapping

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "en": {
                "properties": {
                    "InsertDetails": {
                        "properties": {
                            "Timestamp": {
                                "type": "date",
                                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "description": {
                        "properties": {
                            "firstLine": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "secondLine": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Links": {
                        "properties": {
                            "LinkDetails": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "linkId": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    },
                                    "type": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "dateCreation": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                                    },
                                    "typeOfLink": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "typeId": {
                                        "type": "long"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share your ES index mapping ?

Comment: added index mapping

Answer (score 0):

At first, you want to filter on a nested field. (array of object)
To have coherent result you must have to map this field as a nested one.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Then, you will have to use aggregations.
What you want is to aggregate only "http" values for type_of_link, and return results if the aggregation return more than 2 results.

You query will be a little more complicated:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Links",
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "Links.LinkDetails.typeOfLink": "http"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description.firstLine": "this"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "links": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Links"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "http_only": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "Links.LinkDetails.typeOfLink.keyword": "http"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "several_http": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "Links.LinkDetails.typeOfLink.keyword",
                "min_doc_count": 2
              }
            ,
              "aggs": {
                "complete_match": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 100
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "InsertDetails.Timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And your response will looks like:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "links" : {
      "doc_count" : 4,
      "http_only" : {
        "doc_count" : 2,
        "several_http" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "http",
              "doc_count" : 2,
              "complete_match" : {
                "hits" : {
                  "total" : {
                    "value" : 2,
                    "relation" : "eq"
                  },
                  "max_score" : 0.98082924,
                  "hits" : [
                    {
                      "_index" : "test3",
                      "_type" : "_doc",
                      "_id" : "ed1AkXQBD_dLYq-V78bD",
                      "_nested" : {
                        "field" : "Links",
                        "offset" : 0
                      },
                      "_score" : 0.98082924,
                      "_source" : {
                        "LinkDetails" : {
                          "linkId" : 2342,
                          "type" : "Link",
                          "dateCreation" : "2012-09-21T08:42:09+0000",
                          "typeId" : 404019,
                          "typeOfLink" : "http"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "_index" : "test3",
                      "_type" : "_doc",
                      "_id" : "ed1AkXQBD_dLYq-V78bD",
                      "_nested" : {
                        "field" : "Links",
                        "offset" : 1
                      },
                      "_score" : 0.98082924,
                      "_source" : {
                        "LinkDetails" : {
                          "linkId" : 321313,
                          "type" : "Link",
                          "dateCreation" : "2012-08-21T08:42:09+0000",
                          "typeId" : 404019,
                          "typeOfLink" : "http"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

By playing with the given aggregation you should be able to do what you want.